# Differ null and undefined values in Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

I'm running this code

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval("var out;");
engine.eval("var out1 = null;");
Object m = engine.get("out");
Object m1 = engine.get("out1");
```

And getting m == null and m1 == null.

How to determine if value is undefined or null?

Comment: What does `engine.eval("out === undefined")` return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the correct way to know if the Object returned by the script is `undefined` is by asking `ScriptObjectMirror`:

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;

Object m = engine.get("out");

if (ScriptObjectMirror.isUndefined(m)) {
    System.out.println("m is undefined");
}
```

**Alternative way, using Nashorn internal API**

You can also do it by checking its type:

```
import jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Undefined;

Object m = engine.get("out");

if (m instanceof Undefined) {
    System.out.println("m is undefined");
}
```

Notice that Nashorn did not make the `Undefined` type part of the public API, so using it can be problematic (they are free to change this between releases), so use `ScriptObjectMirror` instead. Just added this here as a curiosity...

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't have a concept of "undefined", so understanding the distinction will require expressing it in the script's language. I suggest using this expression:

```
Boolean isUndefined = engine.eval("out === undefined");
```

Comment: I've added another answer that works even if you don't know the name of the variable, if you got the Object back from the execution of the script, or just don't want to run a script just to know this. It uses `ScriptObjectMirror.isUndefined( object )`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd check

```
engine.eval("typeof out")
```

which will be "undefined" and

```
engine.eval("typeof out1")
```

would be "object"